# numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling on Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, numpy

I am using Windows 7 32 bit version. I have installed Python 2.7. When I try to run a Python program it gives

> ValueError:numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling

How can I fix this? Below is a screen shot how the error looks like. [image]

Comment: That's a Cython error, do you know what versions of Cython, SciPy and NumPy you are using? You may get a more informed answer if you take your question to the SciPy mailing list: http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html

Comment: numpy 1.6.2 scipy 0.16.0b2

Comment: Those are pretty old versions, especially numpy, can you upgrade?

Comment: You seem to be working on Windows... Try installing [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/), or the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) distributions. You can also try [updating a library only](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).